# How to upload to my server and use the URL to point at avideo through another website?

Tags: wordpress, video, file-upload

I am trying to post a video on a WP site, my own site. WP won't let me upload the video. It is 720mb, I have raised the maximum upload to 900mb. Still fails. I think I can use a URL to carry the vid on my WP site. Like putting a youtube video in it, I could be talking rubbish, but I have tried so many times and failed every time. I have managed to upload smaller files, but having split the vid in two, it still fails?
Help would be great